# New EC2 not connecting to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I lost my PEM and had to create a new EC2.  I duplicated it with "make same".  I then tried to connect to the RDS database and it gives me cannot connect with user@.  now, the IP address of the server has changed, but it is in the same security group, so shouldn't matter.

I changed the user to be from anywhere % and flushed privileges.  I even rebooted the DB.  I've tried messing with the security stuff, but everything is as it should be, the same as it was before hand when it was working on the previous server.

either something was not "duplicated" when the EC2 was duplicated or there is something somewhere I have to change because the IP of the EC2 changed.

if they are in the same security group, this shouldn't be an issue however.

any help is appreciated.  as I can no longer connect to the DB with the app.

the EC2 is linux running a docker container for node.

I can still connect to the RDS via local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i still don't know what the issue was, but I was able to get around it by creating a new user.  I'm thinking that the host wasn't actually changing when I was changing it in RDS - even with a reboot.

If somebody comes across this same issue, try creating a new MySQL user.